# Django shell stopped working and act as stranger

Tags: python, django, shell, python-2.7

I am learning Django and I'm still in the first tutorial. When I try to run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

I get the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in pop
ulate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in impor
t_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Elashkar\Desktop\django\mysite\polls\models.py", line 2, in <mo
dule>
    import datatime
ImportError: No module named datatime
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the content of the error in your post rather than linking to an image.

Comment: I think you mean import `datetime`.

Comment: thank you , that's decency sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a typo in the import statement. `datatime` should be `datetime` (a -> e).